# Python Selenium with Safari Webdriver crashes after loading website

Tags: selenium

I've been trying to use safari with selenium. With the latest update, it does not need the prev selenium safari webdriver. However, when I run the below code, it crashes after loading the site. I've restarted my mac and all. Tried thinking of the problem but got nowhere. The code is very simple and I already did the necessary actions on the options such as ticking "allow web automation" and other things. Anyone can help?

from selenium import webdriver

class Instabot:
def **init**(self):
self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
self.driver.get("https://google.com")

Instabot()

Comment: Solved it, it closes because the class finishes running.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://google.com")